# Embedding proof assistance in an application

Tags: beginner, dependent-type, software-request, recommendations, applications

## Context

Perhaps this is too open-ended a question for StackExchange, in which case I apologize, but otherwise here goes:

I have a project I'm toying around with, the core of which is what I'd call "typechecking-guided user interface(s) for data editing."  The idea is to bring some formalism and clarity to the kinds of things that are often done with "data validation" rules in spreadsheets, or ad-hoc javascript handlers in web forms.

Very broadly, the "forward" non-interactive checking version of this would be

```
Given: User-defined formulas (type constructors?) defining "good data"
Given: Some chunk of user-provided data X and a specification of what type it's "supposed" to be / what judgment is supposed to hold for it
Try to prove "X : Good_Data"
Return  or .
```

My goal is for the types / predicates to be
user-supplied, and I'd like to empower them with as expressive a
specification language/logic as practical.  That said, here are some
of the kinds of specifications I'd like to be able to encode (at the
/user/ level, not necessarily going straight into a solver in these
forms).  First off, at the level I've been considering so far, this
all validating /data/ not a /program/, so everything is finite and
known at checking-time.

For context: assume a database- or spreadsheet-like system, where
there are multiple named tables, and each table is a set of 0 or more
records (rows), and each record is a tuple with 0 or more components
(fields).  We are not /necessarily/ assuming that the records in a
table all have the same type or structure, though one might sometimes
want to do that.

### Simple algebraic datatypes (abusing Agda notation a bit)

```hs
record MetaTask : Set where
  field
    id : Nat
    name : String
    
record OrdinaryTask : Set where
  field
    id : Nat
    name : String
        
data Task : Set where
  simple : OrdinaryTask → Task
  withParent: Task → MetaTask → Task
```

If we assume that the constructors are being recorded "in the data", then

```hs
(withParent (simple (OrdinaryTask 3 "wash dishes")) (MetaTask 0 "clean house)) : Task
```

but not

```hs
(withParent (simple (OrdinaryTask 3 "wash dishes")) (OrdinaryTask 0 "clean house)) : Task
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do some inference on a more compact (and user-specified) representation, e.g.

```hs
data OrdinaryTask : Set where
    anon : (id : Nat) → (name : String) → (task_type: literal["ordinary"]) → OrdinaryTask
data MetaTask : Set where
    anon : (id : Nat) → (name : String) → (task_type: literal["meta"]) → MetaTask
data Task : Set where
    anon : OrdinaryTask → Task
    anon : OrdinaryTask → MetaTask → Task
```

from which we ought to be able to infer that

`{id=3; name="wash dishes"; task_type="ordinary"} : OrdinaryTask,` and
`{{id=3; name="wash dishes"; task_type="ordinary"} {id=0; name="clean house"; type="meta"}} : Task`

### Relational integrity constraints

e.g. assume we have a table named `People`, containing only records of type:

```hs
record Person : Set where
  field
    id : Nat
    name : String
```

and I now wish to allow `Task`s to reference `Person`s, e.g.

```hs
record AssignedTask : Set where
  fields
    id : Nat
    name : String
    task_type : String
    assignee : ReferenceTo Person Nat
  
data ReferenceTo (A : Set) (B : Set) : String → (A → B) → Set where
  foreignKey : {tableName : String} → {accessor : A → B} → (key : B) → Set iff
    ∃ (x : A) ∈ tableName s.t. (accessor x) == key /\
    ‌‌‌∀ (y : A) ∈ tableName (accessor y) == key ‌‌‌‌‌‌⟶ x == y
```

So, if `People` contains `{id=1; name="Bob Harper"} : Person` then
`(foreignKey "People" Person.id 1) : ReferenceTo Person Nat` and ideally

```hs
{id= 3; name="wash dishes"; task_type="ordinary"; assignee=1} : AssignedTask
```

It's partially implied in the `ReferenceTo` definition, but we might
want to make table-wide uniqueness constraints like

`∀ x y z. x ∈ People /\ y ∈ People /\ People.id x == z /\ People.id y == x ⟶ x == y` as well.

### Dependent? in a sense? data types

This is the real application I was working on that motivated this
whole line of thinking.  Suppose I want to track medical lab results
in a way tat minimizes opportunities for human or machine error.
Different kinds of tests have categorically different kinds of
results, as well as different units of measure, and I want to validate
such data. (See e.g. https://loinc.org/kb/users-guide/major-parts-of-a-loinc-term/ )

Hard-coding that information into the type/constraint system is
undesirable here; these should be user-editable and/or sourced from
some authoritative party.  So suppose a simplified version of the
problem with these three tables (not counting the actual data to be
validated).

**Table: Properties**

| propertyCode | shortName | name | kind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 718-7 | Hemoglobin | Hemoglobin (Bld) [Mass/Vol] | MassConcentration |
| 95209-3 | COVID | SARS-CoV+SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Ag IA.rapid Ql (Respiratory system specimen) | Presence |
| ... |  |  |  |

```hs
record Property: Set where
  fields
    propertyCode : String
    shortName : String
    name : String
    kind : ReferenceTo ScaleUnits String
```

**Table: ScalesUnits**

| propertyKind | scale | ordList | unitType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MassRatio | Quantitative |  |  |
| MassConcentration | Quantitative |  | M/V |
| NumConcentration | Quantitative |  | /V |
| Presence | Ordinal | (Positive, Negative, Invalid) |  |
| ... |  |  |  |

```hs
record ScaleUnits : Set where
  fields
    propertyKind : String
    scale : Scale
    unitType : ReferenceToAny ExampleUnit String -- non-unique parallel of ReferenceTo.  I'm Not defining it right now.
    
data Scale : Set where
  quantitative : Scale
  ordinal : List String → Scale
```

**Table: ExampleUnits**

| unitType | units |
| --- | --- |
| M/V | ug/L |
| M/V | mg/dL |
| M/V | tonnes per firkin |
| /V | per mL |
| ... | ... |

```hs
record ExampleUnits: Set where
  fields
    unitType : String
    units : String
```

Now, I want the user to be able to write a specification leading to

```hs
    {property="Hemoglobin"; value={qty=12; unit="ug/L"}} : TestResult
    {property="COVID"; value="Negative"} : TestResult
    ¬({property="Hemoglobin"; value="Negative"} : TestResult)
    ¬({property="COVID"; value={qty=4; unit="tonnes per firkin"}} : TestResult)
```

I'm not sure the best way to write it notationally, but the point is
that there's dependence between the `Property` in question and the
type of `Value` that goes with it, and that dependence is mediated by
(user-controlled) data which isn't hard-coded in the type system /
correctness criteria.  So, roughly:

```hs
data TestResult : PropertyKind → Set where
    result : {k : PropertyKind} → (PropertyName k) → (Value' k) → PropertyKind k

data PropertyName : PropertyKind → Set where
    byName : {k : PropertyKind} → (s : String) → Property k -- iff s "resolves" / dereferences to k in Table Properties, that is 
             iff ∃ p : Property ∈ Properties s.t. Property.shortName p == s /\ Property.propertyKind == k 

data Value' : PropertyKind → Set where
    ordvalue : {k = (_, "Ordinal", ordList, _): PropertyKind} → OrdValue ordList → Value' k
    qntvalue : {k = (_, "Quantitative", _ , unitType): PropertyKind} → QntValue unitType → Value' k
    
data OrdValue : List String → Set where
    value : {l : List String} → (s: String) → OrdValue l iff s ∈ l

data QntValue : String → Set where
    value: {unitType : String} → (qty : Number) → (unitString : String) → QntValue unitType iff
    ∃ eu ∈ ExampleUnits s.t. (ExampleUnit.unitType eu) == unitType /\ (ExampleUnit.units eu) == unitString
```

This has been a bit verbose, but I hope it gives a sense of what I'm aiming for here.  Thanks for your help!

## What I want to do

But I'd really like to do more than that.  I'd like to be able to provide user interface support for *constructing* correct data by asking the theorem prover (given user data that is currently incomplete/correct) questions like:

1. If thee data is definitively not correct, why not (and what could be done about it)?
2. If the data *could* be correct, but the theorem prover hasn't proven it, what lemmas might get us there?

Notably, I do not want the end user to have to be comfortable with theorem proving and proof assistants.  The target audience is in the "I can use Excel's niche features" to "I am an ordinary programmer" range.

The research challenges in this for me (though let me know if you're interested) are:

1. Can I identify and extract *actionable* fixes, especially "autocompletion" options for as-yet-unspecified data?
2. Can I extract *user-comprehensible* explanations for why data is not correct.

Which finally gets me to:

## The actual question

Are there interactive theorem provers / proof assistants that lend themselves to being embedded within "ordinary" software and provide nice interfaces for supplying rules and facts and goals, and querying the prover about the state of its efforts to prove said goals?

I know this is very subjective, and I'll be the first to say there's a *lot* I haven't specified here.  Especially, I don't yet know how expressive a logic / type system I *need* in order to support good-enough correctness constraints. The richer the better, as long as the theorem prover support is there (with good translation to and from the internal representation).

So, any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know what sort of things you expect the prover to tackle. Propositional calculus, predicate calculus, type theory? Perhaps some examples expressed in (pseudo)-symbolic form will give us an idea. For example, do you expect to be able to validate "the user entered a prime number"? How complicated are the validation predicates, and how complicated are the types? Can the type be "a list of lists of pairs of integers and booleans"?

Comment: Thanks, Andrej.  I edited it and elaborated a bit (maybe too much?) above.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. I would imagine the sort of problem you're solving has been addressed by people in the past, but I don't know where exactly to look. It feels like it would be more helpful to find out what *techniques* already exist, and not so much how to cajole existing proof assistants into doing what you'd like them to do.

Comment: You would think so, but I haven't found it so far.  Intuitively, I was hoping to leverage proof-assistant-type tools because (the ones I know about) have existing mechanism for translating higher-level statements into a form that can be passed to a general-purpose constraint solver, and then translating results (e.g. witnesses, unsat cores) back to a form that's meaningful in the original context.  I hate reinventing the wheel badly.